# isset() evaluates to true even when the textfields are empty. Why is that?

Tags: php, isset

The first snippet takes data from the two text fields and sends to `action script.php`. The problem is both the `if` statements evaluate to true even if I do not enter anything in the text fields. Why is that ?

```
try.php

<form method='get' action='./action_script.php'>
        <input type="text" id="text_first" name="text_first" /> <br />
        <input type="text" id="text_second" name="text_second"/> <br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

---

```
action_script.php

<?php

  if(isset($_GET['text_first'])) {
        echo "Data from the first text field : {$_GET['text_first']} <br>";
  }
  if(isset($_GET['text_second'])) {
        echo "Data from the second text field : {$_GET['text_second']} <br>";
  }

  echo "After the if statement <br />";
```

Comment: Please try a var_dump on the $_GET to see what you are receiving.

Comment: Look at Zoltan's answer below. It is correct. string(0) means an empty string and that means the variable is set to an empty string (it exists and has a value)... And don't forget to mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because they both are set - the variables exist in the `$_GET` array. Even if their values are empty strings.

Try to check for emtpiness as well

```
 if( isset($_GET['text_first']) && $_GET['text_first'] !== '' )
```

or

```
if ( ! empty( $_GET['text_first'] ) ) {
```

Note that you don't need to use `isset()` because `empty()` does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Comment: Indeed. Advice: use empty(..) instead of isset(..)

Comment: can you please elaborate this _"Because they both are set - the variables exist in the $_GET array. Even if their values are empty strings."_ I didn't understand

Comment: @SuhailGupta upon clicking the submit the `$_GET` array contains *all* the fields as variables regardless of their values - it can be any normal string or an empty string. Think about those variables, as `$_GET['text_first'] = '';` The variable is set but contains no value. That's exactly your case here.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are present in the form it will evaluate to true. To check if a form has been properly submitted and has a value I use **the following if statement**:

```
if (isset($_GET['text']) && !empty($_GET['text'])) { // If the value is set and is not empty
    // Processing code here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are submitting the form without any values, empty values are posted for variables text_first and text_second, but in the $_GET array a key is set for them with null values,
i.e `$_GET['text_first']=''` and

```
$_GET['text_second']=''
```

,but the values are set for the two .

So if u want to check emptiness use empty() ,because isset() returns true as they are set

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
if ( (isset($_POST['DEVICEINPUT'])) && (!empty($_POST['DEVICEINPUT'])) && (trim($_POST['DEVICEINPUT']) !== null) ) {

....

}
```